# Explain a command to install node

Tags: command-line

Original question: [How to install node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65591918/unable-to-install-nodejs-in-ubuntu-v-20-04-1/)
I am unable to understand what this command is doing. Please explain

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Comment: +1 It is a good thing to ask oneself the meaning of a statement before blindly copying it.  You could be more specific though as to what you do not understand and how you tried to analyze the line.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask): "Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `SHELL` scripts, let me explain in detail;

`$()` is the suggested and also more advanced coding style functioning the same as ``, means calling subshell for inline commands.

`[ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ]` to test whether parameter `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` exists or not, if it is empty, `true`.

`printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm"`, as its meaning, format string

`printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"`, same as top

`[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ]` to test whether file `nvm.sh` under its given path exists or not, if exists and size is bigger than zero, `true`.

`\. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`, source (execute) this file, because of SHELL preinterpret, the dot has to be escaped. Or you can replace it using command `source`.

For the basic `Boolean` logical, the whole command is to get string and set it to `NVM_DIR`, then `export` it as **global** parameter.